# Error al direccionar

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

Estoy dando vueltas pero no puedo donde encontrar el error:
tengo wordpress instalado en raiz home. Hice una redireccion para que desde la web se vea como dominio.com. ¿Podrian ayudarme?

mi (.htaccess) situado en public html:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dominio.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Cambiar 'subdirectory' por el nombre del subdirectorio que quiere usar
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?dominio.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ home/index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://dominio.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$"> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio.com.ar$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dominio.com.ar$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dominio.com/$1 [R=301]
```

mi (.htaccess) situado en home:

```
# BEGIN All In One WP Security
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_START
<Files .htaccess>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
ServerSignature Off
LimitRequestBody 10240000
<Files wp-config.php>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
#AIOWPS_BASIC_HTACCESS_RULES_END
# END All In One WP Security

# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.1.2]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dominio.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en el orden de las reglas de re escritura. Las que usa por defecto Wordpress "atrapan" todas las solicitudes antes de que lleguen a las que pusiste tu al final.

Un buen orden para lo que quieras hacer podría ser el siguiente:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.dominio.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://dominio.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

De esta forma primero prueba si la dirección tiene www o no y luego pasa bajo el control de WP.

Adicionalmente, siempre es buena práctica poner este tipo de configuraciones dentro del bloque IfModule correspondiente.

Comment: Gracias!! Funciona! lo que intente es eliminar /index.php cuando redirecciona y no he podido, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: No debería aparecerte el index.php a menos que esté habiendo algún problema con la re escritura. ¿Cómo son las direcciones que te salen?